# JS. при нажатии на одну из картинок она открылась в дргом месте на странице

Tags: javascript, изображения

в папке 100 картинок image_1.jpg image_2.jpg и т.д. все 100 показываются на сайте:

```
<?php 
  for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++) {      
    echo'<img src="image_'.$i.'.jpg" onclick="model_pic('.$i.')">';     
  }
?>
```

надо при нажатии на одну из картинок чтоб она открывалась другом месте на странице

```
<div>
   <img src="image_'.НУЖНАЯ ЦИФРА.'.jpg">
</div>
```

предпочтительно использовать только php и js

Comment: PHP тут не при чём. Вам определенно нужен для этих целей JS.

Comment: я бы как-то вот так сделал: 
for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {      
 console.log('<img src="image_' + i + '.jpg" onclick="model_pic(' + i + ')">');     
}

Answer (score 1):

```js
function foo(img) {
  var field = document.getElementById("xxx");
  var x = document.createElement("IMG");
  x.setAttribute("src", img);
  x.setAttribute("width", "90");
  x.setAttribute("height", "90");
  field.appendChild(x);
}
```

```css
lable {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<lable>
  <img src="http://www.neo2.es/blog/wp-content/uploads/jack2.jpg" onclick="foo('http://www.neo2.es/blog/wp-content/uploads/jack2.jpg')" width="70px" height="90px" />Click me!!</lable>
<lable>
  <br>
  <img src="http://www.bargainbooze.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/320x320/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/1/2103_136.jpg" onclick="foo('http://www.bargainbooze.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/320x320/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/1/2103_136.jpg')"
  width="70px" height="90px" />Click me!!</lable>
<lable>
  <br>
  <img src="http://gnf-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/brendy-slider.png" onclick="foo('http://gnf-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/brendy-slider.png')" width="70px" height="90px" />Click me!!</lable>

<div id="xxx"></div>
```